# How to checkout product programatically?

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, payment-gateway, programmatically

I need to checkout a product when a user comes to a specific block with a specified transfer method. I hope will get help.

Comment: Can you give more information? What exactly do you need? Please edit the post

Comment: I'm using bank payment method. I need user to redirect to payment page when user accesses a url.